# I have completely messed up my Python Env and need help to start fresh

Tags: python-3.x

Long story short, I messed with my Python environment too much (moving files around, creating new folders, trying to reinstall packages, deleting files etc.) My google package doesn't work anymore. Everytime I try to import the package, it says it can't find the module, even though I did a pip install.

I was wondering how I could do a hard reset/delete python off my computer and reinstall it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My pip was installing to a site packages folder inside a local folder, while my jupyter notebook was trying to pull from the anaconda site packages folder.

Answer (score 1):

is your pip working try extracting the required modules.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
create new Venv
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? I ran the lines in terminal and it seemed to run properly.

Comment: check for requirements.txt file in the folder of Venv

Comment: install new python and create new venv and install all requirements in the txt file by pip install -r requirements.txt  new your new venv with all modules are ready

Comment: ahh okay, yeah that makes sense! Thanks Vignesh. There is one issue. When I try to run "Create new Venv" in terminal, it gives me this error: "zsh: command not found: create". Is this the right line of code "python3 -m venv env"

Comment: first do **pip install virtualenv and then try creating new by using virtualenv <path for creating>